# Creating a random complex univariate polynomial

Tags: random, polynomials

I am a newbie in *Mathematica*, but I need to create a random univariate polynomial of degree d with complex coefficients whose entries are random complex variables with real and imaginary parts being independent  distributions with mean value = 1 and variance = 2.

Comment: See for example `RandomVariate`, `Dot` and `Array` or `FromCoefficientRules`

Comment: Also, `FromDigits[]`.

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `FromDigits`  as suggested by J.M.

```
f[d_Integer, var_Symbol] := ExpandAll@FromDigits[
   (#1 + #2 I) & @@@ Transpose[{
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, Sqrt[2]], d]
      , RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[1/2, 2], d]
      }], var]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To figure out parameters of `GammaDistribution`

```
{α, β} /. 
 First@Solve[{Variance[GammaDistribution[α, β]] == v, 
    Mean[GammaDistribution[α, β]] == 
     m}, {α, β}]
```

> ```
>  {m^2/v, v/m}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Just post anothor method about building a polynomial,and the coefficients you can use the @rhermans 's solution to produce.

```
list = RandomComplex[{-2 - I, 5 + 3 I}, 3]
(*{1.83992 + 1.75346 I,3.79133 + 1.05147 I, -0.0638321 - 0.551983 I}*)

AlgebraicNumber[x, list]
(*(1.83992 +1.75346 I) + (3.79133 + 1.05147 I) x - (0.0638321 + 0.551983 I) x^2*)
```

Comment: +1 for `AlgebraicNumber`